# Filter out JSON for only columns I need using jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm using this to parse out the JSON coming from PHP (age_get.php) and it's working great.

```
$.getJSON('age_get.php', function(data) {
  var ticks1=[]
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {                  
  ticks1.push("["+val.index+",'"+val.value+"']");
            });
var ticks6 =[(ticks1.join())]
```

The output is this, which as I said is fine.

```
["[90,'18-24'],[91,'25-29'],[92,'30-34'],[93,'35-39'…'60-64'],[99,'65-69'],[100,'70-74'],[101,'75-99']"]
```

In my PHP file, the mySQL query part is this:

```
$sql = "select * from advanced_data where category like 'age range'";
```

So, basically, I have the PHP already "filtering" the JSON from a much larger table (i.e., with many more columns).

There has to be a better way than creating individual PHP files for each time I need something out of this database, but I'm pretty new to this.

So, the question is, can I have a single PHP file with a query more like this:

```
$sql = "select * from advanced_data;
```

And then in my HTML file/jQuery have something that essentially filters out the JSON for what I need similar to how "where category like 'age range'" works in my PHP file.

Hope that's clear. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, just by way of example take a look at the following. It filters a complete result set without ever returning to the database (actually there isn't a database in this instance, but the principle's the same)... http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/GFbAs

Comment: You can do a lot of filtering in the client(browser) based on different user interactions - yes. In cases where user might make numerous changes in the UI this can be an advantage to work from client side data. On the server side you don't need a new file for each specific query, more you would set up various `controllers` and use parameters sent from client (and/or stored in session) to help determine what needs to be sent back. Best solution is application dependent. A lot of server side processing these days is being moved from the server to the browser though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that technically, but it is not a good idea. When using ajax, it is good to keep the data small.

Instead of get everything from php and search it with js loop, you can improve your php script to let it accept queries.

In your php:

```
<?php 
$whereCategory = isset($_GET['category'])? "where category like '{$_GET['category']}'" : '';
$sql = "select * from advanced_data {$whereCategory};";
...
```

In your ajax:

```
$.getJSON('age_get.php?category=testCategory', function(data) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: This is the type of thing I was looking for. I tried out your code, but am getting a 500 server error. Looks like the main issue is saying that this line is an anonymous function: ` $.getJSON('all_get.php?category=income', function(data) {`

Comment: sorry, there was a copy miss in my js code.`$.getJSON('age_get.php?category=testCategory', function(data) {
  ...
}` should be `$.getJSON('age_get.php?category=testCategory', function(data) {
  ...
});`

Comment: I figured that out before you posted the correction, but I still get the 500 error. I know everything is in the right place, because if I go back to my original PHP file and remove the "?category=" part everything works fine. I think there's another problem.

Comment: Looked up the source of the error and get this: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/html/age_get.php on line 11" Line 11 is "$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);" Any thoughts?

Comment: You are really fast. unexpected T_VARIABLE usually happens when there is an semicolon or bracket missing a line. Please check if your `$sql = "select * from advanced_data {$whereCategory};";` ends with a semicolon.